# Constant Differential Form

Tags: terminology, differential-topology, differential-forms

In the paper I am currently reading, there is the following phrase (first line on page 74 [in this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0700)) :

> Let $\sigma \in \Omega^2(M)$ be **constant**.

What does this mean? To be honest, thinking of $\omega \colon M \to \Lambda(T^*M)$ as a constant map does not make any sense since $\sigma$ needs to be a section.  Also, a differential form could be constant iff $d\sigma = 0$, that is, *constant* is a synonym for *closed*.

Comment: Probably what is meant is *having constant coefficients in some chart*?

Comment: Instead of a guessing game, you could share the source of the quote?

Comment: @CalvinKhor added.

Comment: How about dxdy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of the paper you are reading, these are forms on the torus $T^n$ (something that you should have mentioned in your question), which is a Lie group. Then the natural interpretation of the expression "a constant form" is that it is a form invariant under the action of the Lie group on itself. In other words, if you lift the form to $R^n$, it has constant coefficients.

Comment: What confuses me, is that a page before they use the terminology of a left-invariant differential form which makes sense to me, but on the next page they use constant for the same according to your answer.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek: I did not check but maybe this is because in the context of nonabelian groups left and right invariant forms are not the same thing.

Comment: Nice point! Thanks.